# What happens when you create a new control programmatically without adding it to the form?

Tags: vb.net

I've always wondered if **creating** controls at runtime would have any impact on the program. Emphasis on creating, because I'm not talking about adding the control to the form or any other control.

So here's an example of creating a control but not add it to anything.

```
For i As Integer = 0 to 10
    Dim Temp as New Label With {.Text = "Label " & i}
Next
```

I created 10 labels and I did not add them to any other controls or forms. After this loop, do those controls get disposed of or are they still "around" somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all .NET platform languages, vb.net has a garbage collector. So, when any variables or objects become out of scope (in other words, there is no named references to it), garbage collector destroys it.
You can read more about garbage collection on the internet: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-in-c-sharp-dot-net-framework/amp/

Comment: Thank you Paul for the link. Kinda cool that it does that for you automatically